# Move VLOOKUP using macro and reset search bar

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am hoping you could help me with a query. I am trying to basically create a macro where it sees a formula in a cell, copies it to the cell below, then copy/pastes values only to the original cell. Essentially, it takes the data from the first cell, copies it down and then keeps the values in the original cell. This is being worked with a VLOOKUP, so people would, in theory:

Search for a term

The formula VLOOKUP's the data and pops it in the cell, for example, A2.

To search again, they press this macro button, which makes A2 special values only, but the formula is moved down to the cell below.

This allows for the result from A2 to remain, but the search to happen again.

Any help? I'm not too good with Macro's and trying to play it through has lead to no success.

Thank you

Comment: `trying to basically create a macro` - if you show us what you have tried and where it's failing we'll be able to help a lot more. A [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will enable us to address your specific situation versus the general text you have written above.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Screenshots would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty example to get you started

```
Sub Example()
    Dim c
    With ActiveCell.EntireRow
        For Each c In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            c.AutoFill Destination:=Range(c, c.Offset(1, 0))
            c.Value2 = c.Value2
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
Sub FormulaDown()
  Dim val
  val = ActiveCell.Value
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = ActiveCell.Formula
  ActiveCell.Value = val
End Sub
```